# BufferedReader skips lines not starting with '#'

Tags: java, regex

I have the following construct:

```
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(CFG_FILE)));

    String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.matches(PATTERN)) {
                    //do something
}}
```

The file I am reading looks like this:

```
test1,\
test2,\
test3,\
#test4,\
#test5,\
test6,\
#test7,\
test8
```

I have a break point in the line that starts with `if`, but when stepping through the lines while debugging, I notice that `line` never is one of the lines not starting with `#`. Why is that?

EDIT: here is some more context:

```
private static final String BASIT_PATTERN = "^\\s+basit-.+";

ArrayList<String> featuresConfigEntries = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    BufferedReader featuresConfigBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FEATURES_CFG)));

    String necessaryComponentsFileLine;

    while ((necessaryComponentsFileLine = featuresConfigBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (necessaryComponentsFileLine.matches(BASIT_PATTERN)) {
            final String[] splitNecessaryComponentsFileLine = necessaryComponentsFileLine.split(",");
            for (String necessaryComponentString : splitNecessaryComponentsFileLine) {
                if (necessaryComponentString.matches(BASIT_PATTERN)) {
                    featuresConfigEntries.add(necessaryComponentString.replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim());
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    LOGGER.error("File not found: " + FEATURES_CFG, e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Failed reading file: " + FEATURES_CFG, e);
}
```

The relevant lines from the file:

```
featuresBoot=config,ssh,management,kar,\
basit-core-domain,\
#basit-datasource-ecom,\
basit-connector-ecom,\
basit-datasource-talendmd,\
basit-connector-talendmd,\
basit-datasource-hybris,\
basit-connector-hybris,\
basit-connector-sap,\
basit-connector-jms,\
#basit-order-service,\
#basit-article-service,\
#basit-checkout-service,\
#basit-checkout-service,\
#basit-cart-service,\
basit-server-availability,\
#basit-address-service,\
#basit-user-service,\
basit-connector-atp-engine
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen....every-line should be read.....

Comment: I very much doubt that this is a problem to do with `BufferedReader`. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (I suspect it's a mixture of your pattern being wrong and misdiagnosis in the debugger.)

Comment: this is absolutely useless without seeing what the `patterns` you are trying to match, the precondition of **complete** is not met

Comment: I have added some more code. I have my breakpoint in the line where the if ist. that means, that every line that doesn't start with # returns a null String, right? Why?

Comment: The Pattern isn't relevant because the issue appears to happen before, but I'll add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### BufferedReader does not arbitrarly skip lines:

It has very specific deterministic behavior that has been tested for over a decade.

Your input file does not contain what you think it does.

If when you read lines it is *"skipping"* lines then the lines do not have the appropriate `EOL` markers and are being joined with the next or previous line.

#### Some very basic step debugging will tell you what you need to know.

Putting a break point right after the line is read is the first thing you should have tried.

Hideous debug logging would tell you the same thing as well.

```
while ((necessaryComponentsFileLine = featuresConfigBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
// have you even tried to System.out.println(necessaryComponentsFileLine); ?
    }
```

#### Your regex is not going to match any of that data anyway:

Your pattern is incorrect, it will not match anything that is not starting with at least `1 or more whitespace characters`.

[^\s+basit-.+](https://regex101.com/r/nK3oG2/1)

> ^ assert position at start of a line
>
> \s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ] Quantifier: + Between
>   one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as
>   needed [greedy]
>
> basit- matches the characters basit- literally (case sensitive)
>
> .+ matches any character (except newline) Quantifier: + Between one
>   and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>   [greedy]

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the pattern, but that doesn't fix my issue with certain lines not even getting to the pattern...